# listfragment shows empty view momentarily

Tags: android

when i start my app, which starts with a list fragment, the empty view is shown for less than a second before the list view is shown. I am guessing this is because of the time it takes for the `cursorLoader` to finish populating the adapter from my local sqlite database. Is there a workaround so that the empty view does not show for a few micro seconds every time i open the app?

Here is the layout of the fragment :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/very_light_grey"
    >

    <ListView
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="8dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="nothing yet"
        android:textColor="@color/grey"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hide the TextView and then reveal it once the loader is finished.

Xml:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@android:id/empty"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    .../>
```

Code:

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    findViewById(R.id.empty).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    ...
}
```

**Edit:**

After giving some thought, you have a few choices:

1. Stop using ListFragment, which sets the *empty view* automatically
2. Remove the empty view with `getListView().setEmptyView(null)` and later re-inflate(re-create) and re-set it `getListView().setEmptyView(newEmptyView)`.
3. When the activity is first inflated (`onCreateView()`), set a dummy adapter to it with a single empty item, so the `ListView` doesn't think it's empty. Then later your loader will swap the cursor and use the real data, be it empty or not.

I personally like the 3rd idea the most, and will probably implement it in my own project, as currently I was using solution No.1.

Comment: the `findViewById(R.id.empty)` does not work. Maybe there is another way to access this framework id?

Comment: @faizal ahh missed that it's a framgent. use `getActivity().findViewById(R.id.empty)`.

Comment: that too. But i mean that `empty` does not exist in `R.id`

Comment: @faizal oh. Then use `android.R.id.empty`.

Comment: that works. but the behaviour is still the same..the empty view is still shown for less than a second. It is the same even if i do `getView().findViewById(android.R.id.empty).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` in `onActivityCreated()`

Comment: @faizal setting in the xml should be enough. Make sure to reveal the TextView only after setting the adapters cursor.

Comment: I have not made it visible at all. It seems to be done automatically by the framework. I tried hiding it in `onViewCreated()` as well to no avail.

Comment: @faizal Try this: `getListView().setEmptyView(null);` in `onActivityCreated()`, after super call. If the empty view is hidden now then comment back, i'll post more code.

Comment: ahh that worked thanks! I have edited your answer with the actual code. You should see it after peer review.

Comment: @faizal yes but now the empty view won't work, if your list is empty. I'm updating my answer with a few solutions you can work on.

Comment: it does work. i have set the empty view in `onLoadFinished()`. Tested and works fine.

Comment: @faizal what do you use when setting the empty view? The one as I first suggested `findView...` ?

Comment: yes exactly.  `getListView().setEmptyView(getView().findViewById(android.R.id.empty));`

Comment: @faizal excellent. Glad you came up with your own solution ^^

Answer (score 0):

in onCreateView method you need to set the empty view of the listview object. for example

```
mListView.setEmptyView(view.findViewById(android.R.id.empty));
```

ensure this is done before setting the text of the empty view as well.